# Cannot create directory when started new android project

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors

Cannot create directory:

```
'C:\Users\myDeviceFolder\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\ad6279be8ea6430bdcbb906c758a8940'
```

As it already exists, but is not a directory

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean project. You can do it by 3 ways:

1. In top menu Build->Clean Project
2. Run gradle task "clean" in right menu
3. In terminal print "gradlew clean"

Answer (score 0):

The path tells me problem points to a disposable container. Are you using Continuous Integration? If so, Try cleaning your C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches folder.

If are using task caching or incremental builds, as opposed to global caching that builds up with every build of the project, then you will need to clean your cache from time to time.  Caching a CI system signals repository that a code cache changed during a build, signaling a pull request. Deadlock happens sometimes between push and pulls.  This may not be your fault.  Detailed information unclear.

In order to clean gradle cache in windows, go to:

```
    CD C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches

    DEL /S *.lock
```

created for synchronized access cache.

```
    DEL /S 'C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\$GRADLE_VERSION'
```

timestamps and deltas which change every build.

If this does not work, then there may be a lock on the repository from another worker.  Please check with your team to see if any other member's repository is deadlocked.

Oh, and you can always increment the build version. [edit]

See https://medium.com/cirruslabs/mastering-gradle-caching-and-incremental-builds-37eb1af7fcde for further detail.

Feedback Always Appreciate */\*